# Way To Require Named Parameters in SQL Server Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm wondering if there is a way within a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 to require that named parameters be used? Failing that, a way to tell *if* named parameters were used would suffice.

We're looking at developing a few relatively complex stored procedures that will be called by external systems, and I'm looking for ways to minimize the risk that the external system has data mixed up and/or missing.

The stored procedures will deal with a relatively large number of parameters (for us at least), up to a few dozen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When writing the stored procedures, include MUST PASS variables at the top and optional ones next by assigning default values.

Also you can validate them inside the stored procedure Eg:

```
If @Var = ''
Begin
 SET @Var = 'Default'
END
```

Another thing you can use is exceptions in .Net. When you did not pass a variable that is required by the stored proc, it will throw an exception saying parameter x is required but not supplied (or something similar to this). Catch that exception and send it back to the user in an appropriate way.

Or Validate all the parameters at the application level (Even before getting them into stored procedure)

Answer (score 0):

This sproc uses the "dbcc inputbuffer" command. To use this command you need "VIEW SERVER STATE" permission or belong to the sysadmin role. I suppose you can enforce the named parameter requirement by raising an error when no parameter names are used.

```
create procedure usp_Example
    @LastName nvarchar(50), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @Initials nvarchar(10) = 'Default Initials'
as begin

    declare @inputBuffer  table (eventtype nvarchar(30), parameters int, eventinfo nvarchar(255))
    declare @execStatement nvarchar(255)

    --get sql for sproc execution
    insert into @inputBuffer
    exec ('dbcc inputbuffer (' + @@spid + ') with no_infomsgs')
    select top 1 @execStatement = eventinfo from @inputBuffer

    --get named parameters      
    select s.name
    from sys.all_parameters s where s.object_id = @@PROCID and CHARINDEX(s.name,@execStatement) > 0

    --do stored proc specific operations

end

go
--test with no parameter naming
exec usp_Example 'LastName','FirstName','Initials'
go
--test with parameter naming
exec usp_Example @lastName = 'LastName',@Firstname = 'FirstName',@Initials = 'Initials'
go
--test with parameter naming and default value
exec usp_Example @LastName = 'LastName',@FirstName = 'FirstName'
go
```

Comment: Thanks! This may do what we're looking for. I have to admit I'm surprised that there isn't a simpler way to do- the parser in SQL Server *must* know if named parameters are used, and I would have thought that there would be a way to get this information, or at least a method to require named parameters.

Comment: This is the best I could come up with. dbcc InputBuffer is the only function I could find which tells you if named parameters were used. I was hoping one could use a dmv (Dynamic Management View) to get this information, but I could not find one . Anyway a vote or marking it as correct would be much appreciated.